# window.onbeforeunload runs only when closing window not on refresh

Tags: html, onbeforeunload

I have this function

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {        
          return "Are you sure?";        
    };
```

and I have a button that when the user presses it the window refreshes to update screen values and do some database calls. I added `window.onbeforeunload=null;` in the beginning of the function to disable onbeforeunload but it kept being called.

Is there a way to either disable the onbeforeunload function in my button onclick function or make the window.onbeforeunload get called only on close window not on refresh?

Comment: @SheikhHeera either disable the onbeforeunload function in my button onclick function or make the window.onbeforeunload get called only on close window not on refresh

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/heera/FKNkn/5/

Comment: So, now it seems to always be the way raym0nd wanted it in chrome (Jan 2017)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code should work (should be kept inside head tag between script tags)

```
window.onload=function(){

    window.onbeforeunload = function(){        
        return "Are you sure?";        
    }

    document.getElementById('refresh').onclick=function(){
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        window.location.reload(); // replace with your code
    }
}​
```

[**WORKING DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/FKNkn/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use Cookies. set the cookie as a flag as when you want to refresh the page without having the onbeforeunload function call.

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) { 
...      
   canceled = getCookie("canceled");
         if (canceled == "false" || canceled == undefined)
          {//do ur stuff here
          }
...
}
```

and set your cookie to 5 secs so it expires right after you reload the page.

Comment: how to set coockie to 5 sec?