# call a function when close a window, but not call when refresh

Tags: javascript

I want to write javascript to call a function when user close the tab or the browser, I use beforeunload, but this method also called when I refresh the website. Is there any resolution can make the method only be called when I close the window other than refresh the page?

Comment: No. From the document's point of view, there is no difference between a page refresh and the window being closed: the document is unloaded in both cases.

Comment: It depends on the javascript function.  What I've done in the past is have a handler for unload and a handler for load.  Depending on the call, I set a timer for the unload event, and cancel the timer if the load event fires.

Comment: @Smeegs, I honestly fail to see how you could manage that. You timer should have died when the document was unloaded, and the next `load` event is raised in a different document.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, that's why I said it depends on the function.  My method requires data being written to a cookie or a server.  The 'timer' I specified isn't a js timer.

Comment: @Smeegs, ah, I see. If the server gets involved, that's another story indeed :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's ugly and still not 100%.  Ajax calls are not guaranteed to succeed once the document gets destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, a page refresh is the same as navigating away, so the event will always be triggered.

Maybe you can try something like this

```
window.onload=function(){

    window.onbeforeunload = function(){        
        return "Are you sure?";        
    }

    document.getElementById('refresh').onclick=function(){
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        window.location.reload(); // replace with your code
    }
}​
```

[Example above taken from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085998/window-onbeforeunload-runs-only-when-closing-window-not-on-refresh)
Answered by [werewolf-the-alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741747/werewolf-the-alpha)

Comment: Remember, all answers should be self contained. At least consider what will happen if that link goes offline.